# Rationalizability in Game Theory

Tags: game-theory, simplex

What are the ways in which you can find all set of Rationalizable strategies in a Two-Playe Normal Form Game , like the one given below:

(This is not a homework problem !) Hi. I am not clear on how to find a set of rationalizable strategy (pure and mixed) in a two player game.  I have given the game payoff matrix below that  I am trying to find all the sets of Rationalizable Startegies. I have also given my workout solution below.  I would like to get additional input and feedback on my work.

Consider the following normal form game:

**\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1/2 &  a & b & c   \\
\hline
A & 4,5 & 0,2 & 0,0   \\
\hline
B & 3,2 & 3,0 & 3,2    \\
\hline
C & 0,0 & 0,2  & 4,4    \\
\hline
\end{array}**

Workout:

1) To begin with , I  try to find pure rationalizable strategy. We know that in a two player game Iterated Elimination of Strictly Dominated Strategies is equivalent to Rationalizable Strategies. So here, we see that none of the pure strategies for both players are strictly dominated and hence we can say that there are $\textit{no pure rationalizable startegies}$

2) Now we look at Mixed Rationalizable Strategy:
Here I am reasoning that for player two "b" is dominated by "a" and "c" when Player 2 (P2)  puts probability of 2/3 on "a" and 1/3 on "c" ..in this case b is strictly dominated by a and c.. Thus, eliminate "b" from  P2 strategy profile and we get now a 3x2 game matrix [{A,B,C}x{a,c}]

**\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
1/2 &  a  & c   \\
\hline
A & 4,5 & 0,0   \\
\hline
B & 3,2 & 3,2    \\
\hline
C & 0,0 & 4,4    \\
\hline
\end{array}**

Now I am confused as to how do I proceed further. Do I stop here and say that  [{A,B,C}x{a,c}] are the set of rationalizable strategies or is there more I can do ?

I was thinking of plotting  the new 3x2 game matrix in a graph:
[Probability Plot of Strategies.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDMyZ.png)

But Then through this I see that When $P (probability) < 1/4$, Utility from playing C is better and when $P > 3/4$ then Utility from playing A is better.

So Can I say then P1's strategy of  B is strictly dominated by A and C when p <1/4 and when p>3/4? Does this allow me to delete B from P1's strategy profile?

Let me know please how I can improve my understanding of finding Rationalizable Strategies..

Comment: Part 2) is incorrect. If 2 plays $(2/3) a\oplus (1/3)c$ she gets expected payoffs $(10/3, 2, 4/3)$ against the $(2, 0, 2)$ she gets by playing $b$. The first strategy is not strictly better than the second when 1 plays B.

Comment: Thank you @mlc I didn't see that.  I was thinking for player 2 strategy "b" is never a best response to what Player 1 does so I can eliminate it and get a 3x2 matrix like above and then seeing this matrix I can see that for player one B is never a best response to Player 2 's strategies.  Hence we eliminate B.  Now finally we are left with a 2x2 matrix [(A, C)  x (a, c)] ...these are the strategies that are rationalizble for both.   Now we can use this 2x2 and solve for Nash Equilibrium.    What do you thinkn

Comment: This amendment works out fine. Also, you could use your original argument assuming that the dominating strategy is $(.49)a\oplus (.51)c$. Either way, the conclusions that $b$ can be deleted holds.